# JDL: Multiple Menu

Tags: database, spring-boot, jhipster, jdl

I trying to create multiple menu category using JDL. In one CategoryItem have parentID.

I already created JDL like:

```
microservice * with Category

entity CategoryItem{
    name String required
}

relationship ManyToOne{
    CategoryItem{parrent} to CategoryItem
} 

service * with serviceClass
paginate CategoryItem with pagination
```

If the client calls a method findAll. Can I return JSON format like that:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "car",
    "CategoryItem": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "red car"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "blue car"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "bike",
    "CategoryItem": []
  }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried the DTO option with manual modification of the MapStruct Mapper ?

Comment: Yep! but I don't know how to return JSON like that in DTO? Could you give me a example?

Comment: http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-object-references